# Reportlab, simple issue with adding image to a table

Tags: python, reportlab

So I am creating this simple Reportlab pdf report but I have an issue trying to display the image in the table, it displays (((< PIL.Image.Image image mode=P size=240x60 at 0x201E9A99F60>))) instead of the image

I will post my whole code here so it could benefit anyone looking for how to create Reportlab pdf doc.

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer,KeepTogether,tables
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4,landscape
from reportlab.lib.units import inch,cm,mm
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.platypus import PageBreak 
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.platypus.tables import Table
from reportlab.lib.utils import haveImages, fileName2FSEnc
import datetime
sample_style_sheet = getSampleStyleSheet()
styleSheet = getSampleStyleSheet()
from PIL import Image
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape

PAGE_HEIGHT = defaultPageSize[1]
PAGE_WIDTH = defaultPageSize[0]
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
style = styles["Normal"]

#canvas = canvas.Canvas("emp_tasks_info2.14.pdf", pagesize=landscape(letter))

canvas = canvas.Canvas("emp_tasks_info2.14.pdf", pagesize=(1000,540))

canvas.saveState()
canvas.setFont('Times-Bold',15)

canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 11)
#canvas.line(480,747,580,747)
#canvas.drawInlineImage("C:\\Users\\youse\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\1.jpeg", inch*.25, inch*.25, PAGE_WIDTH-(.5*inch), (.316*inch))
from reportlab.lib.testutils import testsFolder
#gif = os.path.join(testsFolder,'C:/Users/youse/OneDrive/Pictures/1.gif')

#canvas.drawImage( 'giphy.gif', 10,20, width=None,height=None,mask=None)
#canvas.drawImage( 'giphy.gif', 20,500, width=200,height=80,mask=None)
#doc.afterPage()
#canvas.restoreState()

#canvas.saveState()
#canvas.restoreState()
I = Image.open('giphy.gif')
I = I.resize((240,60))

P0 = Paragraph('''<b>A pa<font color=red>r</font>a<i>graph</i></b><super><font color=yellow>1</font></super>''',styleSheet["BodyText"]) 

pp = Paragraph('''<para align=center><b>Calls</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"]) 
p0 = Paragraph('''<para align=center><b>1. Worked on Product-1439</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"]) 
P = Paragraph('''<para align=center spaceb=3><b>Completed below Products for Incorporated:<br/>1. Product-14332.<br/>2. Product-14343. <br/>3. Product-14354. <br/>4.Product-14385.<br/>5. Product-1437 - LS-2574</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"]) 
P1 = Paragraph('''<para align=right><b>Date:</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"]) 
p2 = Paragraph('''<para align=center><b>Regression on completed projects</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"]) 
p3 = Paragraph('''<para align=center><b>Performed Deployment testing and started with Test Plan for Sprint 18</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"]) 
p4 = Paragraph('''<para align=center><b>Worked on Test plan for PRODUCT-1489</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"]) 
p5 = Paragraph('''<para align=center><b>Total<br/>Week<br/>Regular</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"])
p6 = Paragraph('''<para align=left ><b>Week Ending:</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"])
jira = Paragraph('''<para align=center ><b>Jira Task</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"])
sat = Paragraph('''<para align=center ><b>Sat</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"])
sun = Paragraph('''<para align=center ><b>Sun</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"])
mon = Paragraph('''<para align=center><b>Mon</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"])
#mon = Paragraph('<p><b>Mon</b></p>', styleSheet["BodyText"])
tue = Paragraph('''<para align=center ><b>Tue</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"])
wed = Paragraph('''<para align=center ><b>Wed</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"])
thu = Paragraph('''<para align=center ><b>Thu</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"])
fri = Paragraph('''<para align=center ><b>Fri</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"])
employee = Paragraph('''<para align=right ><b>Employee Name:</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"])
name = Paragraph('''<para align=left >Anjpp jol</para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"])
date = Paragraph('''<para align=center ><b>October 10, 2019</b></para>''', styleSheet["BodyText"])

data= [[I, '', '',  '', '','','','',''],
       [p6, employee, '',  '', name,'','','',''],
       [date, '', '',  '', '','','','',''],
       ['', '', '',  '', '','','','',''],
       ['', '', '',  '', '','','','',p5],
       [P1,   '9/28', '9/29',  '9/30', '10/1', '10/2', '10/3','10/4', ''],        
       [jira, sat, sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri],
       [pp, '', '',  '', '','','','1.00',''],
       [p0, '', '', '8.00', '','','','','8.00'],        
       [P, '', '',  '', '8.00','','','','8.00'],        
       [p2, '', '',  '', '', '8.00', '','','8.00'],
       [p3, '', '',  '', '','','8.00','','8.00'],
       [p4, '', '',  '', '','','','7.00','8.00'],
       ['', '', '',  '', '','','','',''],
       ['', '', '',  '', '','','','',''],
       ['', '', '',  '', '','','','',''],
       ['', '', '',  '', '','','','',''],
       [I, '', '',  '', '','','','',''],
       ['', '', '',  '', '','','','',''],
       ['', '', '',  '8.00', '8.00','8.00','8.00','8.00','40.00']]
t=Table(data,style=[('GRID',(0,1),(-1,1),1,colors.white),
                    ('GRID',(0,2),(0,2),1,colors.black),
                    #('GRID',(1,3),(-1,-2),1,colors.black),
                    ('GRID',(0,6),(-1,-2),1,colors.black),
                    #('GRID',(1,-1),(-1,-1),1,colors.black),
                    ('GRID',(1,-1),(-1,-1),2,colors.black),
                    ('GRID',(0,6),(0,6),2,colors.black),
                    ('GRID',(1,5),(-1,6),2,colors.black),
                    #('BOX',(0,1),(-1,-1),1,colors.black),
                    ('BOX',(1,5),(-1,-1),2,colors.black),
                    ('BOX',(-1,4),(-1,-1),2,colors.black),
                    ('LINEABOVE',(0,-1),(-1,-1),2,colors.black),
                    ('LINEABOVE',(4,2),(-1,2),1,colors.black),
                    ('LINEABOVE',(4,3),(-1,3),1,colors.black),
                    #('LINEBEFORE',(0,4),(0,4),1,colors.white),                    
                    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 6), (0, 6), colors.skyblue),                    
                    ('BACKGROUND', (1, 5), (-1, 6), colors.skyblue),
                    ('BACKGROUND', (-1, 4), (-1, 4), colors.skyblue),
                    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 2), (0, 2), colors.skyblue),
                    #('VALIGN',(3,0),(3,0),'BOTTOM'),                    
                    #('BACKGROUND',(3,0),(3,0),colors.limegreen),                    
                    #('BACKGROUND',(3,1),(3,1),colors.khaki),                    
                    #('ALIGN',(3,1),(3,1),'CENTER'),                    
                    #('BACKGROUND',(3,2),(3,2),colors.beige),
                    ('VALIGN',(0,1),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                    ('ALIGN',(0,1),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
                    #('VALIGN',(1,0),(-1,0),'BOTTOM'),
                    #('ALIGN',(1,0),(3,0),'RIGHT'),  
                    ('SPAN',(-1,4),(-1,6)),
                    ('SPAN',(1,1),(3,1)),
                    ('SPAN',(4,1),(-1,1))])

t._argW[0]=6.5*inch
t._argW[8]=.8*inch
t._argW[1]=.6*inch
t._argW[2]=.6*inch
t._argW[3]=.6*inch
t._argW[4]=.6*inch
t._argW[5]=.6*inch
t._argW[6]=.6*inch
t._argW[7]=.6*inch
t._argH[5]=.2*inch
t._argH[4]=.2*inch
t._argH[3]=.2*inch
t._argH[2]=.2*inch
t._argH[1]=.2*inch

t.wrapOn(canvas, 800, 760)
t.drawOn(canvas, 80, 100)
##########
#canvas.showPage()
#P0 = Paragraph('''#<b>A pa<font color=red>r</font>a<i>graph</i></b><super><font color=yellow>1</font></super>''',styleSheet["BodyText"])


canvas.save()


#Story.append(canvas.drawString(50,453,'Patient Lifestyle'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out, 
Instead of using Image.open, I used this image = Paragraph('''''', styleSheet["BodyText"])
 and then I added the varaible image to the table and it is working perfectly :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using the drawImage() property

```
canvas.drawImage('giphy.gif', coordX, coordY, width=240, height=60)
```

Comment: Yes it works this way but that's not what I am looking for. I am trying to add it to the table and make it display in a specific cell of the table.
You can see in my code that I actually commented out canvas.drawimage(..)